# How can I optimize this javascript method code?

Tags: javascript, typescript, optimization

In checkData method I am checking 2 API's status as fulfilled or rejected and based on that I am sending API Data and FailFlag. How can i optimize it as I have used if else statements.

```
const checkData = (data, allData, failFlag) => {
  if (data && data[0].status === 'fulfilled' && data[1].status === 'fulfilled') {
    if (data[0].value && data[1].value) {
      allData.push(...data[0].value, ...data[1].value);
      failFlag = 'NONE';
    }
  } else if (data[0].status === 'rejected' && data[1].status === 'fulfilled') {
    allData.push(...data[1].value);
    failFlag = 'INTERNAL';
  } else if (data[0].status === 'fulfilled' && data[1].status === 'rejected') {
    allData.push(...data[0].value);
    failFlag = 'EXTERNAL';
    console.log('All data with fail flag', allData, failFlag);
  } else {
    Promise.reject('Both are rejected');
    failFlag = 'ALL';
  }
  return { errorFlag: failFlag, accounts: allData };
};
```

Comment: Is data a promise array?

Comment: yes, data is promise array

Comment: When you do `Promise.reject('Both are rejected');`, you're creating a new promise that is in a rejected state, and you're not doing anything with it. What did you intend that line of code to do?

Comment: Would you like shorter code? Because if else is not something that is slow/unoptimized. So if you are looking for optimized code what u have us fine.

Comment: As I want to make shorter code. It was in requirement to do promise.reject and sent failFlag as ALL

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you are passing in `failFlag`, because you're never using that variable. I'm also not sure why you have written `Promise.reject('Both are rejected');`. However, the code can be simplified as follows:

```js
const checkData = ([{status:s0, value:v0}, {status:s1, value:v1}]=[{},{}], allData) => {
  let errorFlag = 'NONE';
  let f0 = s0 === 'fulfilled';
  let f1 = s1 === 'fulfilled';
  if(f0) allData.push(...v0);
  if(f1) allData.push(...v1);
  if(!f0 && !f1) errorFlag = 'ALL';
  if(!f0 &&  f1) errorFlag = 'INTERNAL';
  if( f0 && !f1) errorFlag = 'EXTERNAL';
  return { errorFlag, accounts: allData };
};
```

Comment: I am sending FailFlag to other repository to hide and show error message

Comment: @FrontEndlearner in your code, you are passing a failFlag to the checkData function, but then ignoring its value and overwriting it with a new value. Therefore it makes no sense that you are passing failFlag to the checkData function.